# Frank test for existence of either of two elements

Tags: cucumber, frank

I want to "wait" for either of the two `uiview`s to show up before checking for something,
If I wanted to wait for one specific element I could have used one of the example steps provided in the Frank examples :

```
Then /^I should wait to see "([^"]*)"$/ do |expected_mark|
  wait_for_element_to_exist("view marked:'#{expected_mark}'")
end
```

But I want something like:

```
Then /^I should wait to see either "([^"]*)" or "([^"]*)" $/ do |expected_mark, other_mark|
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Funny, yesterdays WSJ "Best of the Web" column liked the title, "Frank test for existence of either of two elements"  and linked to this question http://www.wsj.com/articles/hillary-rodham-andropov-1465929183?mod=djemBestOfTheWeb

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wait_until function :

```
Then /^I should wait to see either "([^"]*)" or "([^"]*)" $/ do |expected_mark, other_mark|  
  browser.wait_until() {
    expected_mark.exists? or other_mark.exists?
  }
end
```